# XSSI Vulnerability in getJSON?

Tags: jquery, xss

In one application security scanning application, the below  code for `$.getJSON` is coming up as a vulnerability for XSSI (Cross Site Script Inclusion). I am unable to figure out the reason and remedy it?

```js
$.getJSON(getCurrentURL() + "/Filter/Index", {
  actionType: 'PROJECT',
  filter: selectedDuId
}, function(projects) {
  $.ajaxSetup({
    cache: false
  });

  projectSelect.empty();

  $.each(projects, function(index, project) {
    projectSelect.append($('<option />').attr('value', project.Id).text(project.Name));
```